# Undefined function SUM in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

function SUM return value undefined, why I can set result in Text View. It is my code:

```
 mDb = new loaithu( getActivity() );
    Cursor cursor = mDb.GetQueryData( "SELECT khoanThu, money, SUM(money) FROM 'khoanthu' ;" );
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Object result = cursor.getString( 2 );
                Log.i("oke", "" + cursor.getCount());
                String k = (String)result;
                Log.i("SHOWWWWW", "" + k);
                //tv.setText( result);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTK29.png)

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. There is no mention about the data? What is in the DB?  Perhaps attach the result of logging the money field.  Few tips: 1. Do not pass the activity context to the DB instance, 2. Move the cursor close() inside a finally block, 3. Just write "while (cursor.moveToNext())", there is no need for moveToFirst() followed by do-while.

Answer (score -1):

The undefined thing is actually 'money', if you look closely. Take the quotes off 'khoanthu' and you should get on better. SQL doesn't currently realise khoanthu is a table, it thinks it's a character string.

```
SELECT khoanThu, money, SUM(money) FROM khoanthu
```

Comment: I have looked at this and the rest of the discussion multiple times and I really cannot see what is wrong with my answer (a comment from the downvoter would have been nice), but in case it is unclear I have edited it to include the actual select statement.